# Is Modernizr required/used by other packages by default?

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, modernizr

Is the Modernizr required by jQuery, Bootstrap? I seen this nuget package in many MVC.ASP 4.7 projects and just tried to create a new project where it is automatically added. I never used it and I wonder if I can just remove it?

Comment: There is an easy way to discover this for yourself; try to remove the NuGet package. NuGet will warn you if any other packages have it as a dependency.

Comment: yeah i found out about that. But compile wont warn me if the script has been used

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Modernizr](https://modernizr.com/) is a small, simple and open-source JavaScript library that helps us to take advantage of emerging web technologies; HTML5 and CSS3 maintain the look and feel for older browsers that may not yet support these new technologies.

If you create an ASP.NET MVC Web Application, you get this library by default and by expanding the "Scripts" folder.

Modernizr does three things basically.

1. It adds classes indicating feature support.
2. It allows to run feature detection to decide whether to run a script.
3. It injects [html5shiv](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/) for allows old browsers to understand HTML5 elements.

If you don't use any of these features, then there's no point in including Modernizr at all.

Comment: But does it do these things just by being included on a page or do I explicitly need to use it?

Comment: @Jepzen Modernizr doesn't do anything on its own, you have to use its feature detection to change your code. more please visit. https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/0e28e5/how-to-use-modernizr/

Comment: @Jepzen the 3 points  Modernizer do automatically. reference: https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/uploadfile/abhikumarvatsa/modernizr-library-in-mvc-4/

Comment: Thats the link i was looking for!